# How to use the same footer for all email templates in sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid-templates

I have many templates in sendgrid that have the same footer block and have to change a single word in each of them.

I would prefer to factorise the footer block in order to make easier the next changes. For instance, I change a footer block that is included in each template.

I tried to google it but found nothing about this, is it even possible ?

Does someone know how to do ?